# Get the names of attributes from an element in a SQL XML column

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlclr

For this xml (in a SQL 2005 XML column):

```
<doc>
 <a>1</a>
 <b ba="1" bb="2" bc="3" />
 <c bd="3"/>
</doc>
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve the names of the attributes (ba, bb, bc, bd) rather than the values *inside SQL Server 2005*. Well, XPath certainly allows this with name() but SQL doesn't support that. This is my chief complaint with using XML in SQL; you have to figure out which parts of the XML/Xpath/XQuery spec are in there.

The only way I can think of to do this is to build a CLR proc that loads the XML into an XML Document (iirc) and runs the XPath to extract the names of the nodes. I'm open to suggestions here.

Comment: Wow this got an upvote **7.5 years** after I asked it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @xml as xml
DECLARE @path as varchar(max)
DECLARE @index int, @count int

SET @xml = 
'<doc>
 <a>1</a>
 <b ba="1" bb="2" bc="3" />
 <c bd="3"/>
</doc>'



SELECT @index = 1

SET @count = @xml.query('count(/doc/b/@*)').value('.','int')

WHILE @index <= @count 
BEGIN
    SELECT  @xml.value('local-name((/doc/b/@*[sql:variable("@index")])[1])', 'varchar(max)')
    SET @index = @index + 1
END
```

for element 'b'

it returns

- ba
- bb
- bc

You can build a loop to get attributes for each element in the xml.

BTW
The XML in your sample should be closed at closing doc tag.

Answer (score 9):

```
DECLARE @xml as xml

SET @xml = 
'<doc>
 <a>1</a>
 <b ba="1" bb="2" bc="3" />
 <c bd="3"/>
</doc>'

SELECT DISTINCT
 CAST(Attribute.Name.query('local-name(.)') AS VARCHAR(100)) Attribute,
 Attribute.Name.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') Value
FROM @xml.nodes('//@*') Attribute(Name)
```

Returns:

Attribute Value

ba 1

bb 2

bc 3

bd 3

Answer (score 3):

this:

```
declare @xml as xml

set @xml = 
'<doc>
 <a>1</a>
 <b ba="1" bb="2" bc="3" />
 <c bd="3"/>
</doc>'

select @xml.query('
    for $attr in /doc/b/@*
    return local-name($attr)')
```

returns:

ba bb bc

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @xml Xml = '<doc><a>1</a><b ba="1" bb="2" bc="3" /><c bd="3"/></doc>'

Select n.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)')  from @xml.nodes('/doc/*/@*') a(n)
```

Returns
ba
bb
bc
bd