# Need to get attribute name-value pairs for root element only, in T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I've created a table-valued function which returns a list of attribute name-value pairs, when fed an XML fragment, based on Ben Davis's excellent response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241407/get-the-names-of-attributes-from-an-element-in-a-sql-xml-column). It works, but returns a list of all the attribute name-value pairs in the entire fragment, when I'd like to restrict it to just those on the root element. How can I do this? Thank you, from an XQuery newbie.

```
INSERT INTO @attributeList
SELECT DISTINCT
    CAST(attribute.name.query('local-name(.)') AS VARCHAR(100)),
    attribute.name.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @xml.nodes('//@*') attribute(name)
```

ETA: As it turns out after some experimentation, the selector 'node()/@*' works. Thanks to those who helped.

I am using this in a simple data-migration application or data pump front-ending Sitecore. I've written a utility that can take POCO objects in .NET and get them into Sitecore, but now am constructed a migration and logging database. Source objects are stored in one place as XML. Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks, RBarryYoung. That gives the error "XQuery [nodes()]: Syntax error near '<eof>'". I'm like, "Whatever, T-SQL."

Comment: so my initial thought was wrong, let me try a few things.  Can you post some sample XML and what you want to get out of it, that would help.

Comment: It looks like `@xml.nodes('/*/@*')` should work, too

Comment: @JNK you should add that as an answer to people can find it more easily :)

Comment: try:
`@xml.nodes('/*/@*')` and see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442024/getting-specified-node-values-from-xml-document

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered in comments already so this is just a compilation with a bit of explanation.

For the experiments we will use this XML:

```
DECLARE @XML XML =
'<root root_attr="0">
   <leaf leaf_attr="1">one</leaf>
   <brunch brunch_attr="2">
     <leaf leaf_attr="3">three</leaf>
   </brunch>
</root>';
```

And we need to extract the list of the root element attributes: `root_attr="0"`.

For the XPath reference we refer to [MSDN XPath Syntax guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms256122(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, "/" stands for "child" or "root node" if appears at the start of the pattern, "@" stands for "attribute", "*" stands for "any" and "." stands for "current context". Surely this should give us all the root attributes:

```
SELECT
    CAST(attribute.name.query('local-name(.)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) As [Name],
    attribute.name.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') As [Value]
FROM @XML.nodes('/@*') attribute(name);
```

Instead it gives an error: **Top-level attribute nodes are not supported**.
There are two types of **nodes** in XML: <**element**>Element Value</element> and <element **attribute**="Attribute Value" />. So, `/@*` XPath is interpreted as any attribute **for** the root of XML, not **of** the root element. In fact that can be illustrated with:

```
SELECT
    CAST(attribute.name.query('local-name(.)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) As [Name],
    attribute.name.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') As [Value]
FROM @XML.nodes('/') attribute(name);
```

Returning:

```
Name Value
---- --------
     onethree
```

Which is an anonymous node representing the entire XML document. `'.'` XPath would give the same result.

Ok, so we need to specify any **element** at the root of the XML document. The syntax for that should have been "//" (child of anonymous root node = root element) should this expression not stand for "Recursive descent" (all children). Indeed

```
SELECT
    CAST(attribute.name.query('local-name(.)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) As [Name],
    attribute.name.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') As [Value]
FROM @XML.nodes('//@*') attribute(name);
```

Returns full list of attributes of all elements:

```
Name        Value
----------- --------
root_attr   0
leaf_attr   1
brunch_attr 2
leaf_attr   3
```

Ok, now we need a way to say in XPath "root" "element" instead of "rootelement" which is apparently a reserved word. One way is to squeeze in "any", the other - to specify that it should be "node()" unless of cause we know the actual name of the root element.

For the given XML those three are equal:

```
SELECT
    CAST(attribute.name.query('local-name(.)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) As [Name],
    attribute.name.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') As [Value]
FROM @XML.nodes('/*/@*') attribute(name);

SELECT
    CAST(attribute.name.query('local-name(.)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) As [Name],
    attribute.name.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') As [Value]
FROM @XML.nodes('/node()/@*') attribute(name);

SELECT
    CAST(attribute.name.query('local-name(.)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) As [Name],
    attribute.name.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') As [Value]
FROM @XML.nodes('/root/@*') attribute(name);
```

Returning:

```
Name      Value
--------- --------
root_attr 0
```

There we are. A bit of XPath tautology to work around the "//" reserved word.